# Specifying a range within a workbook without specifying the sheet

Tags: vba, excel

If I want to refer to a range within the active workbook in Excel VBA, I can say "With Range("Myrange")". I don't need a sheet name.

Sometimes I want to refer to a range in another workbook. "With MyWorkbook.Range("Myrange")" doesn't work because I have to specify the sheet that the range is in.

Is there any way of referring to the range in a workbook without having to say which sheet the range is in?

Comment: MyWorkbook or ThisWorkBook.ActiveSheet ?

Comment: No, unless you mean whichever sheet is active in that workbook in which case the workbook has an `ActiveSheet` property. (How else could the code possibly know which range you mean?)

Comment: Alex and Rory, Excel must know how to find the range, because if I type "=MyRange" into a cell of any sheet in the workbook, Excel can find the range value even though the sheet that MyRange lives in is not active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a named range and scope it to the Workbook you can use the following to get a named range in any workbook.  You obviously get an error if the name can't be found.

```
wb.Names("Myrange").RefersToRange
```

Comment: Just tried this with two workbooks open, both with a range called "MyRange", and it got the right one each time. Thank you Sobigen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a Named Range (ex: `MyRangeName`) within your workbook. Then in your code use `Range("MyRangeName")` and it will refer to those cells on that sheet no matter what workbook you're looking at.

Comment: Thank you FreeMan, but if I have two workbooks open with the same range name defined in each, the VBA fails with "Method 'Range ' of object '_Global' failed" because it doesn't know which one to use.